# Flow that emits the last value periodically, and when a new value arrives

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, ticker

I want to create a Kotlin coroutines `Flow` that emits values when

1. they change, and
2. periodically emits the last value available, every x duration since the last change or last emit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work -- every time a new value arrives, `transformLatest` cancels any previous lambdas and starts a new one. So this approach emits, and then continues to emit periodically until a new value arrives.

```kotlin
flow.transformLatest { value ->
  while(currentCoroutineContext().isActive) {
    emit(value)
    delay(x)
  }
}
```

Comment: You can drop the `isActive` check. The cancelation will work the same.

Comment: True, but `while` loops with no condition bug me. I like the extra piece of mind provided by the explicit check.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a `Flow` that emits at a regular interval and then just use `combine`. Each time you'd combine the values, you'd really just be passing along the current value of the original `Flow` you are interested in.

```
    // This is the main flow you are interested in. This uses
    // a Flow builder just as a simple example but this could
    // be any kind of Flow, like a (Mutable)StateFlow.
    val emitter = flow {
        emit("Your data")
        // ...
    }
    // This just serves as a timer.
    val timer = flow {
        while (currentCoroutineContext().isActive) {
            emit(Unit)
            delay(500)
        }
    }
    // This will emit whenever either of the Flows emits and 
    // continues to do so until "emitter" stops emitting.
    combine(
        emitter,
        timer
    ) {  value, ticker ->
        // Always just return the value of your
        // main Flow.
        value
    }
```

Comment: This will stop when the last emit finished

Comment: @ShawnThye sure, but that assumes there *is* a last "emit". I used a flow builder here just to have a self-contained example but presumably we are talking about starting with another flow that never "finishes". And if they are starting with a flow that does finish, perhaps they'd want the overall flow to finish too. But it all comes down to what they are looking for. I personally already currently use this solution when combining a "ticker" flow like I've suggested with a MutableStateFlow.

Comment: Yea, I think for his case, he need to use MutableShareFlow or MutableStateFlow depend on his scope :)